# UIImageView show image out of bounds in a UICollectionViewCell sub class

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, ios6, uicollectionview

I have to create a customize UICollectionViewCell to show a image and a name for the image, And on top of the image, there is a frame image which is 2 pixels bigger in width and height than the image. However, no matter what I do, the image seems to be bigger than the frame image. I did the same thing for the table view, and it works perfect.

Here is the code:

```
//GridCell.h

@interface GridCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lblName;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *image;
@end

//GridCell.m

#import "GridCell.h"

@implementation GridCell

@synthesize image, lblName;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"borderUIimgLg.png"];

        UIImageView *bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.width)];
        [bgImage setImage:bg];
        [bgImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
         NSLog(@"BG Image size %f, %f", bgImage.frame.size.width, bgImage.frame.size.height);


        UIImageView *contentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 2.0, frame.size.width-4.0, frame.size.width-4.0)];
        [contentImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [contentImage setClipsToBounds:YES];
        self.image = contentImage;

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.image];

        [self.contentView addSubview:bgImage];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.width - 4.0, 21.0)];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:11.0]];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        self.lblName = label;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.lblName];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The UICollectionViewCell has a size of 67 x 100, so in the code, the bgImage supposed to be always to be 67 x 67 and its origin is (0,0) and the contentImage supposed to have a frame of (0,0,63,63). By debugging, it seems correct. However, the conentimage always bigger than the bgImage. The original size of the image is 80 x 80 though. I have tried setClipToBounds,
setContentViewMode on either the cell.ContentView or the imageView, but none works.

A screenshot about the problem is attached.[image: Image in UIImage view out of bounds]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I also tried to layout all the elements in a nib and in the storyboard, get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using 2 times frame.size.width instead of frame.size.height on the other one

edit, try this:

in the cell, when using initWithFrame methods, use the self.bounds property of the cell.
if you init the imageview inside the border use CGRectInset method to initialize the imageview with smaller bounds and set the imageviews center to same as the contentview of the cell

Comment: that's actually what I wanted, to make the image have equal width and height, which is the same to the width of the cell.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. :) 

I changed `UIImageView *contentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 2.0, frame.size.width-4.0, frame.size.width-4.0)];` to
`UIImageView *contentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectInset(bgImageView.bounds, 6, 6)];`  and magic happens. I need to figure out what's the difference for these two. 4.0 or 6.0 does not matter, just 6.0 is the best for my app.

Answer (score 26):

This might have found the answer by now, try:

```
contentImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Comment: I tried both Fill and Fit and no luck. just tried again, not working :(